Function of several complex variables with prescribed zeros
I accidentally stumbled upon a problem of complex analysis in several variables, and I have a hard time understanding what I read, it might be related to the Cousin II problem but I cannot say for sure. Let me state the problem, maybe you can tell me if you can think of a relevant tool.
Let me start with a simple instance of my problem, I state the general problem later. Is it possible to have an entire function $\tilde \psi(u_1,u_2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|\psi(u_1,u_2)|\leq (u_1-u_2)^2$ on $B(0,1)^c$ and $\psi(0)\neq 0$? I insist that the uniqueness theorem does not work here, for instance $(u_1-u_2)^2$ is an entire function with non-isolated zeros.
(no need to bother further if the answer is no).
General version: I have an entire function $\psi(u)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, of exponential type $1$ (when seen as a function of $n$ complex variables). I want to build another entire function $\tilde \psi(u)$ of exponential type $1$ which satisfies:

$|\tilde\psi(u)|\leq c|\psi(u)|,u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ outside some small ball $B(0,\varepsilon)$
$\tilde\psi(0)\neq 0$.

In dimension $n=1$ it is easy, if $\psi(u)=cu^k(1+o(1))$ as $u\to 0$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N},c\neq 0$, simply define $$\tilde \psi(u)=\frac{u^{-k}}{1+u^{2k}}\psi(u)$$.
From what I understand to the "Cousin II problem", it seems to give conditions to glue two meromorphic functions together, such as $\frac{1}{u_1-u_2}$ on an open domain not containing $0$, and $1$ (or another non-vanishing function) on an open domain containing $0$, but I am not sure it applies.

If I understand your simple version correctly, your function vanishes on the diagonal $u_1=u_2$. Then it vanishes at $(0,0)$ just by continuity.

It is supposed to vanish on the diagonal only away from zero, the question is wether it implies vanishing close to 0 also

Apply the uniqueness theorem for the restriction to the diagonal to conclude that the function vanishes on the full diagonal.

The uniqueness theorem works for functions of two complex variables? How is it stated?

Just define the function $f(z):= \psi(z, z)$, then $f$ is entire function of one variable, and it is zero if $z\in \mathbb{R}, |z| > 1$. Hence, it is identically zero by the uniqueness theorem, in particular $0=f(0) =\psi(0, 0)$.

As simple as that :) ...Thanks
